# Sufficient condition on open subsets to be equal

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers

Let $U,V\subseteq\Bbb C$ connected open non empty, such that their closure in $\Bbb C$, say $\overline U,\overline V$, be simply connected.

Then, is it true that, if
$$
U\cap V\neq\emptyset\\
\partial U=\partial V
$$
then necessarely $U=V$?

I didn't found this result anywhere, I conjectured it and it seems reasonable correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the statement is true.

Let $H$ be the (open) left half plane, and $D$ be the open unit disks about $1$. Put $U = H \cup D$, $V = (\mathbb{C} - \bar{H} \cup \bar{D}) \cup D$. This should serve as a counterexample.

**Edit:**

In the case both $U$ and $V$ be connected, the answer is affirmative. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is locally path-connected, its connected open subsets are path-connected. Suppose $x\in U$ and $y\in V-U$. Since $U$ and $V$ share boundary points, $y\in V-\bar{U}$. Let $\gamma:I\to \mathbb{C}$ be a path from $x$ to $y$ that lies in $U\cup V$. Then $\gamma(t) \in \partial U$ for some $t\in I$, because $U$ and $\mathbb{C} - \bar{U}$ are separated. But then $\gamma(t)\not\in U\cup V$, which is a contradiction.

Note that simple connectedness of $\bar{U}$ and $\bar{V}$ is irrelevant now.

Comment: Thianks for the answer. You're right, I've edited, adding the hypotesis that both open subsets must be connected

Comment: @Joe In that case the statement holds whether or not $\bar{U}$ and $\bar{V}$ are simply connected.